# Files: how to distinguish file lock and permission denied cases?

Tags: .net, windows, file

How to distinguish cases when file operation failed due to file lock and lack of permissions?

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException - it's the same for both cases.

Comment: Is the `HResult` the same as well?

Comment: It is. Any more guesses?

Comment: Are the `Message` and `InnerException` properties of the exception object the same too?

Comment: InnerException is null, Message is the same. Any more blind guesses, or better some real info?

Comment: @user626528 Your comments here read as aggressive and dismissive. They are liable to result in potential answerers choosing not to help you.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I really don't believe blind guess is a type of answer that SO needs to encourage. I'm grateful to any real answers, though.

Comment: That's fine, but in my view, it would be more politically sensible to keep those views to yourself.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I find it stupid to put votes due to "politics" rather than professional considerations. And I don't care about ratings much.

Comment: If this was Win32 then you'd do it by distinguishing between `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` and `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. It seems odd that .net won't pass that information on to you.

Comment: @David Heffernan, probably it's encapsulated somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm not sure that Win32 always draws that distinction either.  IIRC, you often get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when the real issue is a sharing violation.

Comment: @Harry Johnston, that's not good at all. Any ideas how to distinguish it in another way? Check if current program has enough access rights to the file, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my answer here: [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use/937520#937520)

```
const int ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32;
const int ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION = 33;

private static bool IsFileLocked(Exception exception)
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
    return errorCode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION || errorCode == ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION;
}
```

...

```
FileStream stream = null;
try
{
stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   if (IsFileLocked(ex))
   {
    // you know the file is locked
   } 
}
catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
{
    HandleException(ex);
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    HandleException(ex);
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    HandleException(ex);
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
{
    HandleException(ex);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    // you know you dont have permission to the file
    HandleException(ex);
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better you can catch the `IOException` instead of `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Then process it accordingly.

```
 try
 {
     File.Open(_fileName, FileMode.Open, fileAccess, Fileshare.None); 
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
     if (!IsFileLocked(e))
         throw;
 }

private static bool IsFileLocked(IOException exception)
{
    int errorNum = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
    return errorNum == 32 || errorNum == 33;
}
```

This way you can check `FileLocked` exception. Same way try out for `Access denied` exception by checking the appropriate Error Number.

Comment: The code I call throws UnauthorizedAccessException rather than IOException.

Comment: @user626528 Is it important for us to know what your code is? Perhaps different code would lead to `IOException` being thrown.

Comment: As per MSDN link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx UnauthorizedAccessException occurs when the caller does not have the required permission. While IOException occurs when the specified file is in use.

Comment: However, I'm getting UnauthorizedAccessException when I'm trying to delete file which is in use (it's an exe file and application haven't stopped yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can read the ACL from the file using [`GetFileSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), get a handle to the process token using [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then check for the access you want using [`AccessCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To the best of my knowledge, sharing rules never prevent you from reading the security, so if you get an access denied at that point it should be safe to assume that you don't have permission to access the file.  (Strictly speaking, you might have permission to do other things but not to read the ACL, but that would be a rare edge case.)

If `AccessCheck` says that you have access but you get access denied when opening the file, it should be safe to assume it's a sharing violation.  Again, there may be edge cases, such as if the permissions are being changed at the same time you're looking at them, but that should be rare.